# R Shiny: Reduce duplicate code filtering a dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny App that allows users to apply a range of data transformations and outlier exclusion techniques to let users explore the impact of data pre-processing. In the output part, my app displays the results of a t-test, but also a table with descriptive stats and a plot. While the app is functioning fine, I have a lot of copy-pasta code in it, namely all the code that does the pre-processing. Simplified example below:

```
shinyServer <- function(input, output, session){
  output$ttest <- renderText({
#Some functions that transform an input dataframe and assign it to a new dataframe.
    data.transformed <- transform.normal(dataframe, valuevariable, idvariable) #convenience function that applies simple latency normalisation and creates a new variable $transformed
    data.transformed.trimmed <- trim.MAD(data.transformed, data.transformed.trimmed$transformed, 3) #convenience function that filters out data more than 3 Median Absolute Deviations from the Median.
   
    #Some code that does a t-test
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    data.transformed <- transform.normal(dataframe, valuevariable, idvariable) #convenience function that applies simple latency normalisation and creates a new variable $transformed
    data.transformed.trimmed <- trim.MAD(data.transformed, data.transformed.trimmed$transformed, 3) #convenience function that filters out data more than 3 Median Absolute Deviations from the Median.
    
    #some code that makes a plot
    
  })
  
  
}
```

The pre-processing code takes an input dataframe and assigns to a new dataframe, sequentially for all the decisions users can explore (Imagine there´s a dropdown menu for each choice: They select a transformation, then they select a fixed trimming option, then they select a data-based trimming option and so forth. I want to find a way in which I can access the new dataframe created in say output$ttest in output$plot without having to copypaste all the code creating it. Simply calling the dataframe does not work, R treats it as non-existent.

Comment: How about doing the filtering once in a `reactive` and using the result for different outputs? Pretty basic shiny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example on how to use `reactive` with multiple outputs:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
              min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
  ),
  sliderInput("mean", "Mean:",
              min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
  ),
  plotOutput("distPlot"),
  tableOutput("headTable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  manipulatedData <- reactive({
    # Your data wrangling
    rnorm(n = input$obs, mean = input$mean)
  })
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(manipulatedData())
  })
  
  output$headTable <- renderTable({
    head(manipulatedData())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```